# Resume application without losing last activity while Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem with resume/pause application. Now, suppose that we have an activity that I override `onBackPressed()` method and redefine for this method is as follows :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

So, it ran in background without any problem. So, To resume my application, I declare following code in `onResume()` override method :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent resume = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    if ((resume.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
        resume.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        Logger.e(M_tag, "Resume Activity");
        startActivity(resume);
        return;
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

After minimizing the process, I can successfully resume the activity, but the problem that i faced with it, is when I long press on a link in `Internet Browser` and share link with my application, it resumes the activity but don't run the condition

```
if (getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
```

that i defined in the `onCreate()` override method, like below :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getIntent().getAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
        Log.e("App", "In action send mode");
}
```

I've tested `Intent.ACTION_SEND` action while no process in background, and it successfully runs the condition, but now, how can I force my applicatin to run `ACTION_SEND` intent ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not getting OnCreate for a new intent you will be getting [OnNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).

Handle the intent again in this method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll be tested it and reply you the result :)

Comment: Your answer is acceptable for me, It works fairly. Thank you very much :)